# Assigning owner to ContentNotes

Tags: data-loader, notes, jitterbit, contentnote

I am trying to assign the OwnerId to ContentNote (Notes) using Data Loader on new inserts, however I get the following error:

> Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.

Not sure what would need to be specified as I wasn't aware Notes (ContentNote) actually stored in a specific folder. Can someone advise how I can correctly store the OwnerId?

Answer (score 1):

Just received confirmation from Salesforce setting on insert or updating the OwnerId for a ContentNote using the API or any Data Loading tools currently is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you please point to any salesforce documentation that mentions this limitation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

A [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) works similar to [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) and [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm). To relate the ContentNote to a record, you'll need to use a [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm#topic-title) which should solve your issue.

Comment: This does not represent the owner of the note, this will only allow you to setup sharing of the Note with other users.

Comment: Then you might want to use the Note object instead of ContentNote.